# Form não funciona em Chrome 69 mas funciona no 68. O que mudou?

Tags: php, google-chrome

Porque esse form simples não funciona no novo Chrome v69? O que será que tenho que acrescentar ou remover para funcionar de novo?

```
<?php 

require('conISO.php');

if(isset($_POST['modelo'])){$modelo = $_POST['modelo'];}

if(!empty($_POST['cadastro']))
{
if(empty($modelo))
    {$caso = 'modelo';}
else
        {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO multimarcas
        (MODELO)
        VALUES          ('$modelo')");
        $caso = "sucesso";
        }
    }
?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>ERP Smart</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="TESTE.php" name="cadastro" method="post"> 
<table >
    <tr>
    <td>    
<?php 
    if(isset($caso)){
        switch($caso){
            case "modelo":
                echo "Atenção. Falta Modelo!";
                break;
            case "sucesso":
                echo "Parabéns. Produto cadastrado com sucesso!";
                break;
        }
    }
?>
</td>
    </tr>
    <td >
        <input  name="modelo" type="text">
  </td> 
    <td >
        <input name="cadastro" type="image" src="../img/REG.png" value="1">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao mundo web. As pessoas acham que é mais fácil fazer neste ambiente, que engano...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Através desta resposta no Stack Inglês eu consegui resolver o problema.

> Remove extra form data , if "value" attribute is present with
>   non-empty value for  (removed) DOM  As per spec,
>   https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-form-data-set,
>   the constructed "form data set" should not include the value of the
>   image button

Comment: Fornece um link para a resposta e explica melhor a solução para caso alguém precisa da solução futuramente.